# How to develop a docker container for laravel without laradock or docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, dockerfile

I am very new to docker. I want to build a `laravel` development environment with `docker`. I already tried `laradock` but it seemed complicated for me. I was wondering whether it is possible to create a `laravel` development environment without `laradock` or `docker-compose`

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You could create each component of your development environment using containers and [manually network them together](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network/).  This approach would require you to manually start each container and specify the network and volumes they use at runtime.

However, you are adding un-needed complexity by avoiding docker-compose to network your containers together.  By using a compose file you can start your environment with a single command: `docker compose up`.  In the approach outlined above, you would need to manually re-create the containers *every time* you wished to recreate the environment.

[Laradock](https://laradock.io/)'s website has some simple getting started guides that can get you up and running without a full understanding of Docker.  While the learning curve may be steep, it can be beneficial to avoid re-implementing a viable solution.